# How Do I uninstall Fedora from a triple boot involving Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, windows

I have have installed Windows 10,Ubuntu 20.04 and Fedora 33 in this order as a triple boot on my (HP Notebook 15-da0435tx) and now i want to uninstall fedora while still keeping Ubuntu and Windows untouched ? How would I do this I'm unable to find good guides on uninstalling a linux distro in a triple boot? The Ubuntu partition is ext4 and Fedora's is brtfs.

Comment: Un-installing an entire OS isn't really a thing.  Just format the partition that Fedora was installed on.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? One drive or multiple drives? You want to make sure Ubuntu is new default boot and details are different if UEFI or if BIOS. Then you can delete Fedora's partition and if UEFI, the UEFI entry & folder in ESP. If BIOS you must have Ubuntu's grub in MBR.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live USB then remove the Fedora partition.

To ensure that grub is correctly installed, reinstall it as described in the Ubuntu Help: [via the LiveCD terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal).